# Help to create a script to run on system startup

Tags: scripts, acer, aspire-one

I have an Acer Aspire One 725. Turning it everything is fine except that the touchpad is not automatically activated. I dislike manually activate ...
I want the command "sudo psmode" alone is activated. Could you please help please?

I know things like that should create a file that end in .sh, take it to /etc/init.d paste, change permissions, execute a rare command for the system to recognize... but gave no results. Does anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a file `~/.xsessionrc` which will apply settings on login.

```
echo 'xinput --enable "Your Touchpad Name"' >> ~/.xsessionrc
```

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar just a while ago but I disabled my touchpad on startup.

Type `xinput` in Terminal and find your touchpad's name -- mine was "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad".

Add `xinput --enable "Your Touchpad Name"` to Startup Applications.

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you, but I want something turns on since the logging

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you may have accidentally pressed fn + f7 on accident, this disables the track pad. Just press fn +f7 and see if it works.

If not:

Before we go creating scripts, let's try this first.

1. Open the Terminal (ctrl + alt + t)
2. cd /etc/modprobe.d/
3. sudo nano options.conf

In the text editor, type:

```
 options psmouse proto=imps
```

Save the file, close it and run the following two commands.

```
 sudo modprobe -r psmouse


 sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Comment: geoffmcc. I don't have problems with the touchpad. I only want that it turns on in the sturup nothing else. The touchpad turns on with fn+f7, and walks very well. thanks. I'd like an script like "xinput --enable "my touchpad name", how rob says, in my starup

Comment: I guess I must have misunderstood something I read. I was operating on the assumption once you press fn + f7 the track pad will stay disabled, even after a restart. I also thought once you press again and restart it will stay enabled. Anyways, as long as you got it working that's what matters